# Catch SEARCH SHEET (find in sheet) as an event for Excel VBA

Tags: excel, event-handling, find, vba

I would like to highlight selected cell when I am using search (Excel does not help focusing quickly on the found cell)

How can I catch in an EVENT that the SEARCH SHEET is being used?

One option is to catch the Workbook_SheetSelectionChange but how can I get if the search in sheet is active?

Comment: It would be better if you add your try (code) to the question.

Comment: Ctrl + F isn't sufficient?

Comment: I have the following code that works fine BUT I would like it to be executed ONLY if the search is being used ... that is why I need to catch the event or a property that tells if the search is being used

Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)  
Static xlColorPrevious As Variant   
On Error Resume Next   
xLastRng.Interior.Color = xlColorPrevious   
xlColorPrevious = Target.Interior.Color   
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6   
Set xLastRng = Target   
End Sub